# gulp 4 vinyl-ftp Unable to make data connection

Tags: gulp, vinyl-ftp

I'm facing problem with uploading files, randomly it stops with different kind of errors: **Unable to make data connection at Socket. (/aaa/node_modules/ftp/lib/connection.js:935:10)** or **Error: Client aborted**. Sometimes it works when launched e.g. 10 times

```
var deployPaths =
{
    'aaa/public_html': [],
    'bbb/public_html': [],
};

var defaultTasks = [];

function deployMultiple(key) {

    var conn = ftp.create({
        host: 'site',
        user: 'xxxx',
        password: 'xxxxxx',
        parallel: 10,
        maxConnections: 5,
        log: plugins.util.log
    });

    var globs = [

        path + '/some_path/**',
        '!' + path + '/some_path/aa/**',
        '!' + path + '/some_path/bb/**',
        path + '/administrator/some_path/**',

    ];

    // using base = '.' will transfer everything to /public_html correctly
    // turn off buffering in gulp.src for best performance
    return gulp.src(globs, {base: path, buffer: false})
        .pipe(conn.newer(key)) // only upload newer files
        .pipe(conn.dest(key));


}

gulp.task('deploy-task', function (cb) {
    for (var key in deployPaths) {
        deployMultiple(key);
        cb();
    }

});

gulp.task('deploy',gulp.series('clean','git_export','deploy-task'));
```

Please help, Thank you

Comment: Where is your 'path' variable being defined?  It isn't in the code above.

Comment: var path = 'BUILD/gitexport';

Comment: anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

@miojamo

I tested my upload with the same error against 2 different hosting providers with `vinyl-ftp` and `FileZilla` and found that this the error happens only for one of the providers.

In short:

- This is more likely to happen with very long uploads (~22,000 files in my case) due to the error on a provider's side.
- At the same time being tested at another provider gives the other error (`Timed out while making data connection...`) instead of `Unable to make data connection...`.

See my detailed explanations [here in `vinyl-ftp` Github repo issue](https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp/issues/65#issuecomment-497302967).

Hope that sheds some more light on the issue.